# Piping out h.264 encoded video through avconv to vlc

Tags: h.264, vlc, avconv

My end game is to take read a raw video from a file into avconv, h.264 encode it, and pipe it to VLC. However, I cannot seem to get it to work. Even just piping an already encoded video to VLC does not work. Trying:

avconv -i test.mp4 -f h264 - | vlc -

appears to be encoding a video (the cmd line output looks like it is processing frame by frame), but nothing is displayed to VLC. A similar test with an .avi works fine:

avconv -i test.avi -f avi - | vlc -

Is there something different special piping out h264 encoded video?

Answer (score 3):

Specify the demuxer:

`cat test.h264 | vlc --demux h264 -`

> --demux=<string>           Demux module
>             Demultiplexers are used to separate the "elementary" streams (like
>             audio and video streams). You can use it if the correct demuxer is
>             not automatically detected. You should not set this as a global
>             option unless you really know what you are doing.

[VLC command line help](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help)

Comment: While this post may answer the question, it is still a good idea to add some explanation and, possibly, some links to the relevant documentation. Answers with good explanations and references are usually more useful both to the current OP and to the future visitors. Full detailed answers are also more likely to attract positive votes.